# I'm looking for a credit card with daily purchase notifications

Tags: credit-card, alerts

My bank checking account allows me to get notifications/alerts for every check or withdrawal activity over a certain amount immediately.  My credit card allows frequent balance notifications, but not purchase activities notification.  Any recommendations for a credit card with better notification options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

American Express offers a variety of customized alerts, including this one. I set it up to get a text message of my balance every Saturday before 8 AM.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are asking, but I think you can use yodlee.com, mint.com or pageonce.com and add all of your credit card accounts, then login them once a day to get transactions of all your credit cards. There is typically a 2-day delay though.

Comment: And you can log in daily to update.  Additionally in the US you have 60 days to dispute a charge, so a 2 day window is great for fraud protection.

Comment: @MrChrister, +1, sir, you are absolutely right.

Comment: With Mint I get same day alerts; however, it depends on how quickly your credit card processes transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Capital One offers this on their website account management.  You can go into your alerts and specify an alert when charged over a specified amount. I have mine set to email and my smart phone will pick up the email right away.  It has worked pretty good and very quickly every time I have triggered my alert settings.

Comment: At least in Canada, you can't set it to send notifications for expenses under $20, but that's probably not too much of an issue.  You can also get daily balance notifications.

Answer (score 2):

With Bank of America MasterCard and Visa credit card accounts you can be notified of purchases which exceed a threshold you set (sorry, do not recall minimum threshold setting permitted).  Also, you can get alerts when payments are posted to your account, as well.

Answer (score 0):

chase has customizable alerts as well.

Comment: Hi Naveen, can you expand your answer to include more content?